# AngularJS - difference between pristine/dirty and touched/untouched

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) lists many styles and directives regarding forms and fields. For each one, a CSS class:

```
ng-valid
ng-invalid
ng-pristine
ng-dirty
ng-touched
ng-untouched
```

What's the difference between `pristine/dirty`, and `touched/untouched`?

Comment: This is now in the documentation you linked to, under the heading "Using CSS classes".

Comment: You're right :) Althought seems a bit new (alongside the new classes it defines)

Answer (score 280, accepted):

[AngularJS Developer Guide -  CSS classes used by AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/css-styling)

> - @property {boolean} $untouched True if control has not lost focus yet.
> - @property {boolean} $touched True if control has lost focus.
> - @property {boolean} $pristine True if user has not interacted with the control yet.
> - @property {boolean} $dirty True if user has already interacted with the control.

Comment: does it mean that if control is touched it is dirty for sure? is the lost focus considered an interaction?

Answer (score 111):

`$pristine`/`$dirty` tells you whether the user actually *changed* anything, while `$touched`/`$untouched` tells you whether the user has merely *been there/visited*.

This is really useful for validation. The reason for `$dirty` was always to avoid showing validation responses until the user has actually visited a certain control. But, by using only the `$dirty` property, the user wouldn't get validation feedback unless they actually altered the value. So, an `$invalid` field still wouldn't show the user a prompt if the user didn't change/interact with the value. If the user simply tabbed through a required field, ignoring it, everything looked OK until you submitted.

With Angular 1.3 and `ng-touched`, you can now set a particular style on a control as soon as the user has visited and then blurred, regardless of whether they actually edited the value or not.

Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/xmlilley/pen/KwKqqj) that shows the difference in behavior.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to clear the form's validation errors.
form.$setPristine doesn't do it. I've seen other's suggest form.$setUntouched, but looks like this isn't available in angular 1.3 19 beta, which is the version I'm using. I can however call form.field_name.$setUntouched, but doing that for all fields is burdensome, is there a better way?

Comment: `$setPristine` simply makes the form un-`$dirty`. I think you may want `form.setValidity()`. See several helpful answers on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015010/angularjs-form-reset-error).

Answer (score 43):

In Pro [Angular-6 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484236483) is detailed as below;

- **valid**: This property returns **true** if **the element’s contents are valid and false otherwise.**
- **invalid**: This property returns **true** if **the element’s contents are invalid and false otherwise.**
- **pristine**: This property returns **true** if **the element’s contents have not been changed.**
- **dirty**: This property returns **true** if **the element’s contents have been changed**.
- **untouched**: This property returns **true** **if the user has not visited the element.**
- **touched**: This property returns **true** if **the user has visited the element.**

Answer (score 18):

This is a late answer but hope this might help.

Scenario 1:
You visited the site for first time and did not touch any field. The state of form is

**ng-untouched and ng-pristine**

Scenario 2:
You are currently entering the values in a particular field in the form. Then the state is

**ng-untouched and ng-dirty**

Scenario 3:
You are done with entering the values in the field and moved to next field

**ng-touched and ng-dirty**

Scenario 4:
Say  a form  has a phone number field . You have entered the number but you have actually entered 9 digits but there are 10 digits required for a phone number.Then the state is
**ng-invalid**

In short:

**ng-untouched**:When the form field has not been visited yet

**ng-touched**: When the form field is visited **AND** the field has lost focus

**ng-pristine**: The form field value is not changed

**ng-dirty**: The form field value is changed

**ng-valid** : When all validations of form fields are successful

**ng-invalid**: When any validation of form fields is not successful

Answer (score 13):

It's worth mentioning that [the validation properties are different for forms and form elements](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp)  (note that touched and untouched are for fields only):

> ```
> Input fields have the following states:
>
> $untouched The field has not been touched yet
> $touched The field has been touched
> $pristine The field has not been modified yet
> $dirty The field has been modified
> $invalid The field content is not valid
> $valid The field content is valid
>
> They are all properties of the input field, and are either true or false.
>
> Forms have the following states:
>
> $pristine No fields have been modified yet
> $dirty One or more have been modified
> $invalid The form content is not valid
> $valid The form content is valid
> $submitted The form is submitted
>
> They are all properties of the form, and are either true or false.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> ng-pristine - To check if the **form is touched** but **not modified**
>
> ng-dirty - To check if the **form is touched** and **modified**
>
> ng-touched - To check if the **form is just touched**
>
> ng-untouched - To check if the **form is untouched**