# What if I want to validate the input value when I move using tab key?

Tags: angularjs

If you try running [this source](http://plnkr.co/edit/5BV7J1STAt0KpB8OZEa3?p=preview) and move to the next tab using Tab Key, It doesn't display required validation message. How can I validate including this case??

Code for validation is like the followings.

```
<p>Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</span>
</p>
```

Comment: fire validation msg in ng-blur..

Answer (score 1):

`ng-model-options` of Angular 1.3+, which will update `ng-model` on `blur` that will get dirty on `blur`

```
 <input type="text" name="user"
         ng-model="user"
         ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
```

Comment: @verystrongjoe does it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `$pristine` and `$touched` states of your form. You could do something like this:

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$touched || (myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid)">
```

Here is the updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/wTSKGJ0FUx3TVCMYA7R9?p=preview

See also this question: [Angular - difference between pristine/dirty and touched/untouched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025102/angular-difference-between-pristine-dirty-and-touched-untouched)