# Angular ng-options setting pristine to false on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Something about the following combination of "multiple" and "as" in the options expression is making ng-options set pristine to false when the form first loads. Is this an angular bug? Does anyone know of a workaround?

http://plnkr.co/edit/c9ZIgiiisntkJJBeFFdy

```
<select multiple name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
      ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in data.availableOptions"
      ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
```

Comment: This is because it's not really pristine because you have default options selected. What you're looking for is `!myForm.$touched`, which tells you whether the user has interacted with it yet.

Comment: @CSS while that works, this still seems to be a bug, because setting a default value on any other field, including a select without `multiple` doesn't change `$pristine`.

Comment: @CSS According to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025102/angular-difference-between-pristine-dirty-and-touched-untouched) that's not true. I'm interested in whether the value has changed, not whether the select has gained/lost focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an angular bug.

> Yep, that looks like a bug. You don't need select as, but you need multiple. It's got something to do with us checking if the view / model has changed after the options have changed. When that's the case, we call $setViewValue with the new selection, which triggers a call to $setDirty.
>   As a workaround you could add a directive that runs after ngOptions which forces $pristine = true and $dirty = false after the initial loading.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13211

Answer (score 0):

When you set data.selectedOption the angular select the options and set pristine to false.

You can set true manually with .$setPristine() method.

Comment: I don't think that's true. It didn't do that pre-1.4, and it doesn't do this without the "as"