# how to assign a css class to a form control programatically

Tags: angular

I have an `input` field. The field should not be empty. If it is, I want Bootstrap's `is-invalid`  class to be assigned to it. The problem I am facing is that if I just click on the field, do not type anything and then leave the field, the field doesn't turn red (`has-error` doesn't get assigned to the field). However if I type something and delete it completely and then leave the field, the  field turns red.

The `HTML` is

```
<input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" [ngClass]="validateField('firstName')" (blur)="setFieldStatus('firstName')" required>
```

`.ts` is

```
  validateField(field:string){
    console.log("validating field: " +field)
    return this.helper.displayFieldCss(this.signupForm,field);
  }

 /*mark a control field as touched on losing focus from that field.*/
  setFieldStatus(field:string){
    console.log("inside setFieldStatus for field "+field)
    const control = this.signupForm.get(field);         
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {             
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true }); 
      }
  };
```

helper.ts

```
 displayFieldCss(form: FormGroup, field: string) {
    console.log("in displayFieldCss for field "+field);
    if(!form.get(field).pristine) { //check for validity only if the user has interacted with the field. Without this check, the default field will have red border.
      let fieldValid: boolean = form.get(field).valid;
      return {
        'is-invalid': !fieldValid, // if fieldvalid returns false i.e. field is not valid then we want has-error css. So set it to true (opp. of fieldValid)
        'is-valid': fieldValid //if fieldvalid returns true i.e. field is valid then we want has-success css. So set it to true (value of fieldValid)
        //'has-feedback': this.isFieldValid(field)
      }
    } else {//if field is pristine (not touched by user at all) then dont display error or success
      return {
        'is-invalid': false, // if field is pristine (not touched by user at all) then dont display error or success
        'is-valid': false//if field is pristine (not touched by user at all) then dont display error or success
      }
    }
  }
```

My logic is, in template, `ngClass` gets `is-valid` or `is-invalid` depending on whether user has interacted with the field or not. I do not want the field to be red when the form loads up (pristine check handles that)

when the user leaves the field, I mark the field `touched`. Now, I can see the issue that `[ngClass]` gets assigned when the field is created but it doesn't get updated when `(blur)` is called. I need to update `[ngClass]` when `(blur)` is triggered but don't know how to. `blur` is handled in component's class while `[ngClass]` is in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to set the `class` attribute on your component programmatically on the `blur` event:

*template (html)*

```
<my-element (blur)="onBlur()"></my-element>
```

*component class (ts)*

```
@ViewChild('my-element', {read: ElementRef}) el: ElementRef;
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

onBlur() {
  const classVal = some condition ? 'is-valid' : 'is-invalid';
  this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'class', classVal);
}
```

You could add the `this.renderer.setAttribute...` line to the function that currently runs on `blur`. There are also other methods you could use like `addClass` and `removeClass` -- I've linked the API above.

Comment: Didn't work. `if(fieldValid) {
            this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'class', 'is-valid');
            this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'class', 'is-invalid');` I inspected the element. the classes were not added. However, once I type something in the field then the classes get added (the old code)

Comment: also, I had to use `el.nativeElement`. using only `el` caused runtime exception

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to include the .nativeElement, editing my answer to include that now. Can you create a minimal reproduction in a Stackblitz? This approach should work, so there must be something else affecting it. I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I should have been checking `touched` instead of `pristine` status. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025102/angular-difference-between-pristine-dirty-and-touched-untouched.  Changed the condition in `displayFieldCss` and happy days! No need for `blur` check as well.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the problem. I should have been checking touched instead of pristine status. stackoverflow.com/questions/25025102/…. Changed the condition in displayFieldCss and happy days! No need for blur check as well.