# How to format and validate email node js

Tags: node.js, angular, validation, email, express

I would like that email had format like: a@b.c.

Which is the best way to do it?

I have a component for registration and I have the field like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

In my usersRouter I have the function for registration:

```
router.post('/users/register', (req, res) => {
        ...
        const user = new User({
            ...
            email: req.body.email,
            ...
        });
     ...
});
```

Also, I use mongo and in the UserSchema I have this for the email:

```
email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188007/5695162

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use regular expression something like that:

Solution 1:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

*Sample code:*

```
const emailToValidate = 'a@a.com';
const emailRegexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;

console.log(emailRegexp.test(emailToValidate));
```

---

Solution 2:

Because you use angular, you are able to validate the email on front-end side by using Validators.email.

If you check angular source code of Validators.email [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.8/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L60-L365), you will find an EMAIL_REGEXP const variable with the following value:

```
/^(?=.{1,254}$)(?=.{1,64}@)[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+(\.[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?(\.[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)*$/;
```

You could use it on back-end side too, to validate the input.

Comment: Bear in mind that the above solutions allows emails without TLD, like this: a@a

Answer (score 30):

You can use email validator module:

```
var validator = require("email-validator");
validator.validate("test@email.com");
```

Or, if you don't want any dependencies:

```
var emailRegex = /^[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~](\.?[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z`{|}~])*@[a-zA-Z0-9](-*\.?[a-zA-Z0-9])*\.[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])+$/;

function isEmailValid(email) {
    if (!email)
        return false;

    if(email.length>254)
        return false;

    var valid = emailRegex.test(email);
    if(!valid)
        return false;

    // Further checking of some things regex can't handle
    var parts = email.split("@");
    if(parts[0].length>64)
        return false;

    var domainParts = parts[1].split(".");
    if(domainParts.some(function(part) { return part.length>63; }))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Source:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-validator

https://github.com/manishsaraan/email-validator/blob/master/index.js

Comment: there is a problem with timeout. I use email-validator but sometime it show an error as "{"message":"Please provide a valid email address.","reason":"Timeout"}" so my question is how to get rid of this timeout error. Note: when I send mail to this same address by usying gmail account, it is sending.

Comment: email-validator fails on 7 of these addresses: https://codefool.tumblr.com/post/15288874550/list-of-valid-and-invalid-email-addresses

Answer (score 4):

I like validator.js

from the docs:

```js
var validator = require('validator');

validator.isEmail('foo@bar.com');
```

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Answer (score 2):

In my project i've used email-validator module

```
npm i email-validator


const emailvalidator = require("email-validator");
if(emailvalidator.validate(req.body.email)){
      // Your call to model here
}else{
   res.status(400).send('Invalid Email');
}
```

You can install the module from below link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-validator

Comment: there is a problem with timeout. I use email-validator but sometime it show an error as 
"{"message":"Please provide a valid email address.","reason":"Timeout"}"
so my question is how to get rid of this timeout error.
Note: when I send mail to this same address by usying gmail account, it is sending.

Comment: @MuhammadAbubakarZorrain, it seems to be a bug, you can open an issue in the github repository. https://github.com/manishsaraan/email-validator/issues

Answer (score 0):

I like the Joi library for those. Enables you to validate all kinds of things easily!

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.string().email().trim();

// "john@doe.com"
const validEmail = Joi.attempt('john@doe.com', schema);

// trimmed "john@doe.com"
const validEmail = Joi.attempt(' john@doe.com ', schema);

// throws error
const validEmail = Joi.attempt('john@doe', schema);
```

More on Joi here:
https://joi.dev/api/